# How can I check if a Express.js session is active?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, session

I was trying to check if a session is active in an Express.js session but couldn't find anything relatable. I am storing my sessions in a MongoDB store with `connect-mongo`. I basically need to check if a user's session is active to display an active icon on their avatar (front-end not included in this question). I only want to create the back-end API to do that.

Thank you for help.

Comment: What is your definition of an "active session"?  What makes it active?

Comment: @KrisztianNagy - If you read the actual question, this is not going to help them solve the problem they're trying to solve.  They want to show the active status to OTHER users when OTHER users are logged in.

Comment: Yeah @jfriend00 so, how facebook does it. Let's say you visit facebook and there's a little green dot on the front-end of your profile. So what I'm trying to do is to recreate the back-end of that functionality. Like fetching user's active status. Hope this made sense.

Comment: Please define what you mean by "active"?  That's where everything starts.  You have to define that.

Comment: Can't you send request from the server periodically? If the logged-in client can answer in some way you can determine if they are online... if there is no answer, you can turn the client off

Comment: @jfriend00 users' browser and session are open and they are browsing the website

Comment: @KrisztianNagy I think about creating a websocket API... what do you think?

Comment: Do you have a live webSocket connection to all active users?  If not, then you have no connection to the browser, so then it's probably a matter of how long with no activity would you consider something no longer active?  YOU have to define what you mean by active.  That is the first step here.

Comment: Yeah I'm thinking about creating a websocket api to ping every second or 1 minute. Sorry for not being able to define it properly.

Comment: Well, a webSocket may be overkill (and a more load on your server), but it all really depends upon what you mean by "active".  That's why I'm trying to get you to figure that out.  We can't recommend a technology solution until we know what problem it is that we're trying to solve.

Comment: Let's say I log in to my website. Start using it. Then ping the API every x minutes/seconds. I retrieve the active status of the user. If the user doesn't ping the server every x minutes/seconds API is going to return that, that user is not online/is offline. @jfriend00

Comment: If you already thinking of WebSocket I would recommend to check out Socket.IO at https://socket.io/#examples

Comment: Yeah I plan to use socket.io if I go with a websocket api but I want to know if there are other scalable options too.

Comment: The problem with that is it's not very efficient for battery powered devices because they're expected to constantly be talking to the server.  And, mobile browsers will shut your communications down as soon as it isn't foreground to save battery.  It would be better to just record and keep track of natural activity between client and server and use that as an indication.  if there are client-only actions that are considered "active", then you can notify the server every once in awhile when those are happening.

Comment: Alright @jfriend00 that solution doesn't seem too bad. If the UX will be better then it'll be much better to go with that instead of websockets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to accomplish this using Redis. I have set a TTL(time-to-live) for each object so that if the user doesn't send a GET request to a certain route in some amount of time the object will be removed from Redis thus making the user `"incative"` when others fetch their status.

Answer (score 0):

Right now you probably have a bunch of sessions in your database. In order to find them in your express-app, you need to create a schema so mongoose knows what to look for:

```
// models/session.js
const sessionSchema = new mongoose.schema ({ 
  expires: Date,
  session: String,
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Session', sessionSchema);
```

Then, somewhere in your code you need to use mongoose to look into this collection, eg:

```
const sessions = await Session.find({}).lean();
console.log(sessions) // sessions stored in the database
```

and then you should have your results. You probably have many sessions so you need to look into the session key and filter out what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have managed to accomplish this using redis and TTL for each object so that if the user doesn't send a GET request to a certain route in let's say 2 minutes the object will be removed from redis thus making the user "incative"